# Solving a system of 3 linear equations where one variable is the product of the other 2 variables.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am given the following system of linear equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c} 
2x+2y+mxy=5 \\
(m-1)(x+y)+xy=1 \\
3x+3y-xy=m+1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where $m \in \mathbb{R}.$

I am asked to find the **number of values of $m$** (so not the values themselves, just the number of values) for which the system has solutions $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. I tried a bunch of things.

First, I tried performing gaussian elimination on the system using the system like so:

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 2 & m \\
    m-1 & m-1 & 1 \\
    3 & 3 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
    y \\
    xy \\
  \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  5 \\
    1 \\
    m+1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
But I got stuck. I saw that $2^{nd} column = 3^{rd} column$ so the determinant of that matrix is $0$. So the ranks of the matrices $A$ and $\overline{A}$ (augmented $A$) must be the same, smaller than $3$ (since $det(A)=0$). I thought I could use this fact but couldn't come up with anything.

Then I tried factoring a $2$ in the first equation and a $3$ in the last equation and came up with this other system:

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  2 & m\\
    m-1 & 1\\
    3 & -1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x+y \\
    xy \\
  \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    5 \\
    1 \\
    m+1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried similar things here but I still couldn't find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

**PS:** I know from the source of this problem that the answer is $1$ (so the number of real values of $m$ for which the system has solutions $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is $1$).

Comment: These aren’t linear equations, at least not in $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of
$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & m & 5\\
    m\color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1\\
    3 & -1 &m+1
\end{bmatrix}}_{=:A}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x+y \\ xy \\ -1
  \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 0\\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\qquad(*)
$$
the possible values of $m$ correspond to the roots of the determinant of the matrix denoted $A$ above. This determinant is zero iff
$$
(m^2 - 2m + 3)(m + 2) =0\ .
$$
Since we are working over reals, only $m=-2$ has to be studied.

---

*Later edit:* I am trying to answer the question in the comments part, doing things as detailed as i can. Let $m$ be a value that accepts a solution $(x,y)$ of the given system of algebraic equations of degree two. We have then an associated *homogeneous* linear system $(*)$ above with a non-trivial solution. (That $-1$ makes it non-trivial.) (Alternatively, in the school they claim that an overdetermined system has a solution if the rank of the "*extended matrix*", in our case $A$, coincides with the rank of the matrix of the system. The latter rank is at most two, so we have an other argument for getting $\det A=0$.) This implies that the matrix of the system, denoted by $A$, is singular. This implies that $\det A=0$ (for this specific $m$). We compute this determinant (linear operations on the rows or Sarrus) and factorize. The only real possible value for $m$ is $m=-2$.

(This was one implication, we used the given condition to restrict the possible values of $m$, now we have to consider "them" in particular, this only possible value $m=-2$, for the other implication.)

So we have to look then specifically, to see if $m=-2$ really leads to a real solution. The system in the unknown $s$ (sum, $s=x+y$), and $p$ (product, $p=xy$), becomes for $m=-2$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & -2 & 5\\
 -3 & 1 & 1\\
  3 & -1 &-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  s \\ p \\ -1
  \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 0\\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}\ ,
$$
we get $s=-7/4$, $p=-17/4<0$, and since $p<0$ we have (two) real solutions (for this one value of $m$).

Comment: I understand how you manipulated the system to get a $3 \times 3$ matrix, but I'm sorry to say that the following part is a bit foggy for me. You said "the possible values of $m$ correspond to the roots of the determinant of the matrix denoted $A$ above" and then you found the determinant of $A$ and equaled it to $0$. This is the part I do not understand. Why does $m$ correspond to the roots of the determinant of $A$. And why must the determinant of $A$ equal $0$. Can you please expand a little bit on that to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Add your 2nd and 3rd equations to get $x+y=1$ or $m=-2$

If $m\ne -2$, you get
$$xy=\frac{3}{m}=2-m$$
and therefore $$m^2-2m+3=0.$$
This has no real solutions.

If $m=-2$, you get $x+y=-\frac{7}{4}, xy=-\frac{7}{4}$ and so $x$ and $y$ are roots of $$4t^2+7t-17=0.$$

This has real roots and so we are finished.